# Using a likely/unlikely as argument of return in linux kernel

Tags: optimization, linux-kernel, built-in, likely-unlikely

Just see this construction in the linux kernel, and I can't get what does it mean.

```
110         return unlikely(sl->sequence != start);
```

I know that `likely`/`unlikely` are made with `__builtin_expect` function described here:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html

> You may use __builtin_expect to provide the compiler with branch prediction information.

But what kind of branch prediction hints is possible for unconditional branch??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just guessing here, but imagine the function is inlined by the compiler, and you have this in the calling code:

```
if (functionUsingUnlikelyForReturn()) {
   // Do something
} else {
   // Do something different
}
```

*then* it's entirely reasonable for the branch prediction to take note of the hint.

Answer (score 4):

The "unlikely" does not give a likelyhood for returning from the function, but rather an expected value for the return value. My guess is that the function is inlineable, so this is a hint for optimizing the function's caller.